# Installing lxml for Python 3.3 on windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7, pip, lxml

I'm trying to install lxml on Windows 7 for Python 3.3, but when I do:

```
pip install lxml
```

I have this error :

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I checked if gcc.exe was in the MinGW folder, and it seems correctly installed.
I tried :

```
gcc -v
```

And I obtain in one of the response lines : `gcc version 4.6.2`

Here's a part of the path :

```
C:\Python33;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Python33\Scripts;C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages
```

I really don't understand why the installation doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution, this is a little bit crazy, and I don't know why it works. I'm using 32bits and 64 bits but it seems that the programm only search for lxml in the 32 bits Python folder, so if someone is in my case :

1. Install lxml with the installer providing by [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), but when it's done, move lxml folders into the **32 bits** Python folders
2. Install pyKml in the **64 bits** Python folder using `pip install pykml`
3. Change Windows path by adding : `C:\Python33_32bits;C:\Python33_32bits\Scripts;C:\Python33_32bits\Lib`, juste change Python33_32bits by your 32 bits Python folder
4. With those step I can import lxml and got no more problem with : `from lxml import etree`

May be one of those steps are unnecessary but it works for me so I prefer share all the steps I done. (And sorry for my english grammar ...)